# Validation Rule, Make Lookup Field Required if Picklist Values Selected

Tags: picklist, lookup, validation-rule

Why does this validation rule give me syntax errors?

BUSINESS REQUIREMENT:

IF "agreement type" picklist field EQUALS "apple" OR "orange" AND "Related Member" lookup field IS empty THEN throw validation rule error message.

VALIDATION RULE:

```
AND(
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Agreement_Type__c, “apple”),
ISPICKVAL(Agreement_Type__c, “orange”)
),
ISBLANK(Related_Member__c)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule looks ok to me except for the quotes you have used around the values apple & orange..

I took the exact one you had in my dev org and it complained only on the quotes.. change it to single quote like belwo and it should work..

```
AND(
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Agreement_Type__c, 'apple'),
ISPICKVAL(Agreement_Type__c, 'orange')
),
ISBLANK(Related_Member__c)
)
```